# Plotting convex hulls crossing 180 degree international date line and calculating area

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, mapping, r-sf

I am trying to plot species range areas using convex hulls to then calculate the area and create a figure.

There is a well known issue with the 180 degree international dateline that I have been trying to remedy following many examples on SE, e.g:

[How to remedy a path that crosses the international dateline with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998580/how-to-remedy-a-path-that-crosses-the-international-dateline-with-r)

This comes close to what I am aiming for but plots in mapview not ggplot2:
[How to construct/plot convex hulls of polygons from points by factor using sf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622586/how-to-construct-plot-convex-hulls-of-polygons-from-points-by-factor-using-sf)

Here is my attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(ggspatial)
library(mapproj)
```

Generate species occurrence data, with some points crossing 180 longitude

```
df <- data.frame(species = rep("sp1",8),
                 longitude = as.double(c(-170.2, -179.5, 55.9, 167.6, 154.3, 101.7, 70.54, -165.94)),
                  latitude = as.double(c(8.25, -24.75, 24.25,19.25, 33.45, -15.5, 5.56, 4.6)))
```

Pacific centered world map from map_data and plot

```
world <- map_data("world2") 

map<-ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
col = "#78909C", fill = "#78909C", lwd = 0)+
coord_map(orientation = c(90,0, 150), ylim = c(-40, 40), xlim = c(20,210))
```

[my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGA2d.png)

Add occurrence points to the map

```
map +
geom_point(data = df, mapping = aes(x = longitude, y = latitude))
```

[map with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoGuU.png)

Construct minimum convex hulls from species occurrence data.

```
species.sf <- df %>%
  st_as_sf( coords = c( "longitude", "latitude" ))
```

Create hulls and wrap around dateline

```
hull<- species.sf %>%
  summarise( geometry = st_combine( geometry ) ) %>%
  st_convex_hull()

hull<-st_wrap_dateline(hull,options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES", "DATELINEOFFSET=180"),
   quiet = TRUE)
```

Plot hull - cuts at 180 but clearly not including all occurrence points

```
map +
geom_point(data = df, mapping = aes(x = longitude, y = latitude))+
geom_sf(data=hull, inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

[incorrect hull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmeOf.png)

Calculate Area of Hull - must be incorrect based on the hull shape

```
st_area(hull)
```

I have also tried applying a pacific centred CRS to the map, points and hulls but suspect that I am applying these either in the wrong order or wrong places? I am very new to using R for spatial analysis so any help hugely apriciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below a solution to your problem. I used the function `st_shift_longitude()` from the package `sf`.

**Reprex**

- Your data (no changes)

```r
df <- data.frame(species = rep("sp1",8),
                 longitude = as.double(c(-170.2, -179.5, 55.9, 167.6, 154.3, 101.7, 70.54, -165.94)),
                 latitude = as.double(c(8.25, -24.75, 24.25,19.25, 33.45, -15.5, 5.56, 4.6)))



world <- map_data("world2") 

map<-ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               col = "#78909C", fill = "#78909C", lwd = 0) + 
  coord_map(orientation = c(90,0, 150), ylim = c(-40, 40), xlim = c(20,210))
map
```

[image]

- Convert your `dataframe` "df" into the `sf` object "species.sf" and shift the longitude with `st_shift_longitude()`

```r
species.sf <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_shift_longitude()


map + 
  geom_sf(data = species.sf, inherit.aes = TRUE) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(40, 210), ylim = c(-40, 40))
```

[image]

- Compute the convex hull polygon based on the `sf` object "species.sf" with `group_by(species)` (for your general case)

```r
hull <- species.sf %>%
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise( geometry = st_combine( geometry ) ) %>%
  st_convex_hull()
```

- Convert back the `sf` object "hull" into the `dataframe` object "hullDF"

```r
hullDF <- hull %>% 
  st_geometry() %>% 
  st_coordinates() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

- Vizualisation of the final result

```r
map + 
  geom_point(data = df, mapping = aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  geom_polygon(data = hullDF, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y), fill = "lightgreen", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

- Compute area of the hull polygon (needs the `units` library to convert the result in squared km)

```r
library(units)

hull_area <- hull %>%  
  st_area() %>% 
  set_units(km^2)

hull_area
#> 74714882 [km^2]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Gemma Galbraith. I hope the above answer meets your needs. If so, please consider marking this answer as "accepted" to make it easier for other SO users to find the right answers. If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @lovalery, this is exactly the solution I am after. Would st_shift_longitude() also work if I wanted to add other spatial layers to this map? For example the coral reefs vector from the natural earth package? The goal here would be not only to map the coral reef habitat for a figure but also to calculate the area of coral reef within a convex hull. This might be better as a separate question though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Gemma. You are welcome. Glad I could help and thanks for validating the answer. Always hard to make constructive comments without seeing the data but yes, I think you should be able to achieve your goal using the same approach developed here.  I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.

Comment: Another follow up to this question @lovalery. If I has multiple species in the occurrence data how would I apply the st_shift_longitude to the multiple hulls? I have tried implementing group_by which works for the first step:                    hulls<- fish %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise( geometry = st_combine( geometry ) ) %>%
  st_convex_hull()
# However, then an error following the shift
st_crs(hulls) <- 4326
hulls<-group_by(Species) %>% 
  st_shift_longitude(st_geometry(hulls))
Error in st_shift_longitude(., st_geometry(hulls)) : 
  unused argument (st_geometry(hulls))

Comment: Hi @Gemma. O.K. I'll give you an answer in two steps. 1°) the error message you get is related to a syntax error in your "tidy" code. For this to work, the part `%>% st_shift_longitude(st_geometry(hulls))` should be modified as follows: `%>%st_geometry()%>%st_shift_longitude()` (furthermore, "hull" should not be indicated in the brackets). But, don't make any changes, wait for point 2 ;-)

Comment: 2°) Reading the code again this morning, I realized that I made a stupid mistake: it is useless to execute the `st_shift_longitude()` function on convex hull polygons because the points have already been shifted. Once is enough !!!! Therefore the code can be lightened.

Comment: Conclusion: I have edited my answer above to (i) remove this unnecessary step, (ii) integrate the `group_by(species)` into the code so that it can be applied to your real data (i.e. your fish data) (iii) provide you with a fully tidyverse version of the code (as I understand that is the syntax you prefer). I hope this will solve your problem efficiently. If it does, feel free to upvote my answer ;-) Cheers.

Comment: Last point: in the function `group_by()` I wrote `species` with a lower case "s" because in the  `sf` object `species.sf` it is written that way. Reading you, I think that in your real data set (i.e. fish data) it is written with a capital "S". So, if that's the case, don't forget to make this modification so that everything runs smoothly. Cheers.